# Running Multiple Entity Framework Core Queries in parallel

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use .Net Core 7, Entity Framework and the Controller <-> Service <-> Repository <-> DBContext Pattern.

**Controller**
is only responsible for REST

**Service**
Contains the business logic
In this specific case (only occurs once). I would like to merge three entities and execute the queries in parallel.

```
 await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(x => Task.Run(x)));
```

But I got an Exception:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. ?
```

**Repository**:
My repositories all use a DB context. To be able to execute queries in parallel, I have to instantiate several DbContexts. I am not sure how to proceed. Should each method create its own DbContext?  This does not seem to me to be the right approach.

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly MainDbContext _db;

    public PersonRepository(MainDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<Person?> GePersonAsync(string userId)
    {
        Person? person = await _db.Person.SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.UserId == userId);
        return person;
    }

    public async Task<Person?> GetPersonAsync2(string userId)
    {
        using (var db = new MainDbContext())
        {
            Person? person = await _db.Person.SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.UserId == userId);
            return person;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `IDbContextFactory` to create multiple `DbContext` instances in a single request scope.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're implementing the _repository anti-pattern_: this is unnecessary in EF because your `DbContext`'s `DbSet` members **are** the repositories already (and the `DbContext` **is** your unit-of-work), so you're just abstracting-an-abstraction, which is a waste of time. (and using repositories means your consumers can't compose their own `IQueryable<T>` queries themselves, which hampers code and design iteration during development).